# Multiple pattern Matching in R

Tags: r

For a multiple pattern matches (present in a character vector), i tried to apply `grep(paste(States,collapse="|), Description)`. It works fine, but the problem here is that

Consider,

```
Descritpion=C("helloWorld Washington DC","Hello Stackoverflow////Newyork RBC")
States=C("DC","RBC","WA")
```

if the multiple pattern match for "WA" in the Description Vector. My function works for "helloWorld **Wa**shington DC" because "WA" is present. But i need a suggestion regarding the search pattern not in the whole String but at the end of String here with DC,RBC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Firstly, please correct the formatting of your post, including the case (upper/lower) of your R code. `C` is a function, but not the one you mean. `Paste` isn't a function, and `Collapse` is not an argument to `paste`. It's a good idea to proof-read your question to make sure it all makes sense and is (more or less) free of typos. Random capitalisation is just confusing. Finally, it's not really clear what you're asking. The "edit" link is just below your question.

Comment: Potential clue: `grep("[ab]$", c("abc", "ab", "ba"))`

Comment: Hello Hugh , thanks for the answer it works if i want to search which ends with an [ab] or [ba]. But here my input is an Character Vector which as many Patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like the following. I've taken the liberty to clean up your example a bit.

```
Description <- c("helloWorld Washington DC", "Hello Stackoverflow", "Newyork RBC")
States <- c("DC","RBC","WA")

search.string <- paste0(States, "$", collapse = "|") # Construct the reg. exprs.
grep(search.string, Description, value = TRUE) 
#[1] "helloWorld Washington DC" "Newyork RBC"
```

Note, we use `$` to signify end-of-string match.